# Does series defined on the sequence $(-1)^n$ converge

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I wanted to use the example of the series $\sum_1^\infty (-1)^n$ to show that a series may diverge even though all of its partial sums are bounded.

But then I realised that I do not know how to show that the above written  series diverges.

Hence the question , Also do tell me if the example that I have chosen is correct.

Comment: Hint: the difference between consecutive terms has limit $0$ for a convergent series.

Comment: You can use the $\epsilon$ formalism to show that for for any sufficiently large $n$, the difference between partial sums does *not* go below $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $S_n = \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k$. We have: $S_{2n}=0, S_{2n+1} = -1$. Viewed these as subsequences of the $S_n$ sequence, you see that these subsequences converge to different values, hence the $S_n$ diverges, and so the series diverges.

Comment: Exactly what I was going to say, you beat me to it.

Comment: Haha. Thanks for letting me know. i just typed quick.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate method to prove divergence is to notice that for $a_n = (-1)^n$ we have

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n \neq 0$$

thus the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ must diverge.